# Play youtube video within iphone app

Tags: iphone, video, youtube

I need to play some youtube videos within my iPhone app, can I use the native youtube app?

I've tried to embedding the video, but it doesnt work well.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to play YouTube videos is to just use the URL scheme for YouTube. Opening a YouTube URL will open the video in the YouTube app instead of in Safari:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZH30T99MaM";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: yeah, i've tried and it close my app i need to runt it within my iphone app

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `UIWebView` and open `m.youtube.com` link inside it.

Comment: Here's a beautiful example: [1]http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html

This covers both a UIWebView and also opening the YouTube app.